# How do I refactor my model?

Tags: java, oop

I have object model, which describes an instructions for worker:

- go to location
- get an item
- go to another location
- pick another item
- ........
- finish job

In my app I need a list of this instructions to guide worker in his job.

The types of instructions are very different, that's why data which is required to describe instruction can be different. For changing location I just need the location id, *but* for getting item I also need an item id, quantity and item name, alongside with location id.

So my model looks like that:

```
public class Instruction{
    int locationId;
    int itemId;
    String itemName;
    String quanity;
    Type itemType; // can be Type.GET_ITEM, Type.CHANGE_LOCATION etc.
}
```

So I have the situation where I describe different entities with one model.

Should I live with that, or there's a way to eliminate duplication?

What I want is to keep the ability to  store all instructions in a list, but to make models more clean.

Comment: if you want to eliminate duplication, you need to override hashcode and equals method (can be generated with an IDE or with annotation using lombok). Then use a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
interface Instruction {}

class LocationInstruction implements Instruction { 
    int locationId;
    public String toString() { return "Go to the location " + locationId; } ;
}

class ItemInstruction implements Instruction {
    Item item;
    public String toString() { return "Pick item " + item.toString(); } ;
}

class Item {
  int itemId;
  ...
  public String toString() { return "Item{itemId: "+itemId+"}" ;}
}

class Actions {
  public List<Instruction> getInstructions();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract common information into an abstract class and create classes for specific types of instructions that extend the abstract class.

Your abstract class could offer some common methods for common operations and/or define methods the subclasses need to implement.

That can give you a clean interface to work with in your lists.

Take a look at [polymorphism in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).